# Building Revolution R Enterprise from the RevoEnt-10817.enterprise.tar.gz file?

Tags: r, revolution-r

How to build Revolution R Enterprise from the RevoEnt-10817.enterprise.tar.gz file
downloaded from Revolution Analytics website ?

My system is Windows 7. I have already installed R 2.15 and Rstudio. 
Will it overwrite the original R installation ?

Can anybody guide me towards some step-by-step document/material ?

Comment: What does the website of Revolution R say? It is their product. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/downloads/gpl-sources.php they just say it is GPL Source code. Will the methodology be same as we build any R Package from Source-code ?

Comment: @purnendumaity it looks like that don't offer support (maybe yet)for R2.15(only R2.14). So I don't think it will be straight forward task. Maybe it is better  to ask on their [forum](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?20-Installation)

Answer (score 1):

I could not quickly find a description on the RevoR website that describes how to install this source package. Like @agstudy suggested, you could post on their support forums and see if they can help you. It looks like you need to build R from source if you want to use the version of RevoR you downloaded, which requires you to install some additional tools. Probably those tools are the same as the ones you need to install for normal R, and can be found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

But why do you need RevoR? Normal R is equally powerful, and you have already installed R and Rstudio, so you're good to go.

Comment: The use of RevoR gives 3-4 advantages like as below:

1.Out-of-memory Big Data objects (alternative ff)
2.Direct analysis of SAS and SPSS data (alternative sas7bdat)
3.Step wise Debugging using breakpoint (no alternative)
4.Hadoop: Cloudera CDH3 / CDH4 connector ( alternative Rhipe+hadoop)

I know these alternative/workaround exists, but those path is not exactly straight/smooth, so I was looking for for using RevoR.

Comment: @purnendumaity You're absolutely right. The ability to do linear regression on billion row datasets is a bit of a bonus. I also like the fact that its easy to use all of the CPU's on the PC, which means its a lot faster than standard R.